# How to show ads after second activity close?

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

I have created a `show_ads()` function to show interstitial ads, and now I want to show the ads after a second activity close, but there is fragment in the second activity. I need to do like this when i press back_button
"fragment->second_activity->ads->first_activity".

Can you tell me how to do that?